# In a short story, can I write "ahhhhh!" as an exclamation of the surprise experienced by a group of young kids?

Tags: word-usage

-“Ahhhhhh!” they all exclaimed in unison.

Comment: In a short story you can write anything you want.

Comment: Everyone knows Ahhhhh only has 5 Hs. ;)

Comment: I agree heartily with Hot Licks but, not quite an answer but more than a comment, I strongly doubt a group of kids would all come up with the same expression when surprised. There would surely be some Ooooh!s and What-the!s to go around. And please forgive GArthurBrown. He is a slave to SpellCheck.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could write that. It wouldn't seem strange to a native English speaker. They might think you could write that bit *better*, but it wouldn't be jarring in the sense of "oh, this person doesn't speak English with the familiarity of a native speaker".